# Split 1 function in PHP using WebSocket

Tags: php, websocket

I have one instantiation inside a function I need to separate this function into two functions, where they could make this instantiation from the first function that will establish a 1 websocket connection with the server, and the second function will keep receiving the data from the server, in resume 1 function make the connection with the server and the other function receive the data from the server, this way I'm not going to make one connection every time I need to receive one information from the server, I will make the connection once, this code is already done and is working I only needed to separate in a way of that.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use WebSocket\Client;

function recursive()
{
    $client = new Client("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime");
    #$client = new Client("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv");

    #$arrayToSend = ['op' => "unconfirmed_sub"];
    #$arrayToSend = ['op' => "subscribe", 'args' => "orderBookL2:XBTUSD"];
    $arrayToSend = ['op' => "subscribe", 'args' => "trade:XBTUSD"];
    #"request":{"op":"subscribe","args":["trade:XBTUSD","instrument:XBTUSD"]}}

    $client->send(json_encode($arrayToSend));

    $arr = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr2 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr3 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr4 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr5 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr6 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr7 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr8 = json_decode($client->receive());
    $arr9 = json_decode($client->receive());

    $value = $arr->x->out[0]->value;

    $amount = $value / 100000000;

    echo $amount . "<br>";

    sleep(1);

    recursive();
}



$i = 1;

recursive();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

require **DIR**."/vendor/autoload.php";

use WebSocket\Client;

class Connection extends Client
{

```
//construct
public function __construct($sWsUrl)
{
    parent::__construct($sWsUrl);
}

//deal
public function deal($aData)
{
    $this->send(json_encode($aData));

    $aReceive1 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive2 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive3 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive4 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive5 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive6 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive7 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive8 = json_decode($this->receive());
    $aReceive9 = json_decode($this->receive());

    $iValue = $aReceive1->x->out[0]->value;
    $iAmount = $iValue / 100000000;
    echo $iAmount . "<br/>";

    sleep(1);
    $this->deal($aData);
}
```

}

$oClient = new Connection("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime");

$aToSend = ['op' => "subscribe", 'args' => "trade:XBTUSD"];

$oClient->deal($aToSend);

now you will make connection once,no duplicate